# Verify if the sum of two subspaces are equal to $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble in this exercise because i am not sure if I'm dealing with it in the right way. The exercise is to consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$:

$$U=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb {R}^3\mid  x=y=z=0\}$$

$$V=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb {R}^3\mid z=0\}$$

And the purpose is to show that $U+V=\mathbb {R}^3$ and if it's also a direct sum.
Well, what I noticed is that any element of $u$ is the null vector. Then I let $u=\vec{0}$ and $v=(x,y,0)$ where $u \in U$ and $v \in V$. Therefore,

$u+v=v=(0,0,0)+(x,y,0)=x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)$
which is
$V=[(1,0,0),(0,1,0)]$.
That was my conclusion. But isn't equals to $\mathbb {R}^2$? what I did wrong?

Comment: That's right, the sum is not a full space. Just double check if the question is asking you to prove it, or asking you whether it is true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct.

You also can just show that a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can't exist in $U+V$ and that's a proof that $U+V\neq \mathbb{R}^3$. For this case, since in any of $U,V$ the $z$ entry is zero, you can just say that any vector with $z\neq 0$ can't be generated as sum of vectors of $U$ and $V$.